# How is the formula derived for finding the field of view given drift time and declination of a star?

Tags: astronomy, observational-astronomy

How is the formula for field of view derived given the drift time of a star and its declination?

$FOV  = (drift\ time \cdot \cos(declination)\cdot360 ) / 86164$

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: the 360 is in degrees, the earth rotates one full rotation (360 deg.) in 1 day, which is 86164 seconds.  This gives you an angle for the FOV.  But the star may not be perpendicular to you from the earth, so you must adjust by the cos factor.  This can be derived geometrically.